# Is there a way to add a custom tooltip to the second level columns of the drilldown on highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add additional information to the columns in the second level of the drilldown.
For example, for "stuff 1" in "Category 1" I want to show a list of 4 items (text) then in "stuff 2" i n "Category 1" I want to show a list of 6 items (text) .

I just found ways to add generic information to the tooltip but no specific information for each column.

http://jsfiddle.net/7qv6x3pj/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Title 1"
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Stuff'
                    }
                },
                colors: [
                    '#1b6601',
                    '#2dae01',
                    '#BBDDA5',
                    '#FF0',
                    '#f20808'
                ],
                series: [{
                    name: "Title",
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [
                        {
                            name: "Category 1",
                            y: 3,
                            drilldown: "cat1"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Category 2",
                            y: 4,
                            drilldown: "cat2"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Category 3",
                            y: 7,
                            drilldown: "cat3"
                        }
                    ]
                }],
                drilldown: {
                    series: [
                        {
                            name: "Category 1",
                            id: "cat1",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "stuff 1",
                                    4
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 2",
                                    6
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 3",
                                    5
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 4",
                                    6
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Category 2",
                            id: "cat2",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "stuff 1",
                                    4
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 2",
                                    9
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 3",
                                    4
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Category 3",
                            id: "cat3",
                            data: [
                                [
                                    "stuff 1",
                                    2
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 2",
                                    5
                                ],
                                [
                                    "stuff 3",
                                    4
                                ]
                            ]
                        }]
                }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `tooltip.formatter` and additional property saved in the point object. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    if (this.point.tooltipInfo) {
      return 'Something: <br>- ' + this.point.tooltipInfo.join('<br>- ');
    }

    return this.y;
  }
},
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    name: "Category 1",
    id: "cat1",
    data: [{
        name: "stuff 1",
        y: 4,
        tooltipInfo: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
      },
      {
        name: "stuff 2",
        y: 6,
        tooltipInfo: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
      },
      [
        "stuff 3",
        5
      ],
      [
        "stuff 4",
        6
      ]
    ]
  }]
}
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vjoprc7t/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter